# Rayon find_any, and return the found item's value

Tags: rust, rayon

Let's say I have a function `f` with signature

```
fn f(a: u8) -> Result<bool, SomeError> {}
```

Now I have a `Vec<u8>` and I wish to find if there's any element in this Vec whose value by `f` is `Ok(b)`, and, in that case, return the value `b` (and stop calculating `f` for the rest of the Vec). I wish to have a function with signature

```
fn my_function(v: Vec<u8>) -> Option<bool> {}
```

Here's my first implementation:

```
fn my_function(v: Vec<u8>) -> Option<bool> {
  let found = v.par_iter().find_any(|a| f(a).is_ok());

  match found {
    Some(a) => Some(f(a).unwrap()),
    None => None
  }
}
```

But I'm doing one useless `f` calculation at the end. How could I refactor the code to avoid this additional `f` calling?

Rayon's `map`, `filter`, `reduce` won't work because they go through the whole Vec, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rayon's `.flat_map(…)` method](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.3/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.flat_map) will apply `f` to each element, treat each return value as an iterator, and flatten all of those results into a single new iterator. [`Result`s can be used as iterables of one (if `Ok`) or zero (if `Err`) elements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.iter), so this has the effect of unwrapping `Ok` results and discarding `Err`s. You can then apply `.find_any(|_| true)` to get the first available resulting value without requiring a second call to `f(…)`.

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn my_function(v: Vec<u8>) -> Option<bool> {
    v.par_iter().flat_map(|x| f(*x)).find_any(|_| true)
}

fn f(a: u8) -> Result<bool, SomeError> {
    if a == 42 {
        Ok(true)
    } else {
        Err(SomeError {})
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", my_function(vec![0, 1, 2, 42, 3, 42, 0]));
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SomeError {}
impl std::error::Error for SomeError {}
impl std::fmt::Display for SomeError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:?}", self)
    }
}
```

#### [Playground Output](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5c80d2b79834de148d66a93a53b57063)

```
Some(true)
```

Comment: Or even use `.next()` instead of `.find_any (|_| true)`

Comment: @Jmb Unfortunately there was [`no method named \`next\` found for type \`rayon::iter::flat_map::FlatMap\``](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66f65832e495e9bf2b4e4ee0efaa81ff) (or [in `ParallelIterator`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.0.3/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html)).